# Replace Macro in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

This macro in Excel 2016 did not work and did not give any error. Any idea?

```
Sub Replace()
    
        Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
        Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B62")
    
        For Each cell In rng
            cell = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(cell, "ÃƒÂ¼", "ü")
        Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: Use some other word rather than `Replace` and `Cell`. May be you can use `MyReplace()` and `MyCell`. Also try to use `Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(...)`.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the worksheet you are working in?